# Redirect to page to sub-folder without changing URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mirror.php [R=301]
```

I want to redirect someone going on `domain.com/some directory or file` to `mirror.php` in the root directory yet retain the URL.

For example, I would type in `domain.com/bob.php`, I would want to go to mirror.php but still have the domain.com/bob.php in the url.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: and have you tried changing `(.*)` to `some directory or file` ? Also note that `[R=301]` means redirect to.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Yes, I mean, any file or directory. Thanks, I edited some code I found on the Internet but I cant get it to do as I wish. `

Comment: If you want to keep the URL in the browser’s address bar, then why do you _explicitly_ redirect (by using the flag `[R=301]`) …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mod_alias` will do what you're looking for. You can alias all files to mirror.php with something like `AliasMatch ^(.*)$ /var/www/domain.com/mirror.php`. Unlike `mod_rewrite`, can't use `AliasMatch` inside of a `.htaccess` file. You'll have to put it into your `httpd.conf`.

Here's the page on [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html)

Comment: Thanks, Hmm interesting... I was hoping to use `mod_rewrite`.